# Modifying a string by replacing

Tags: javascript

How can I replace some words in a string with some other words? For example:

```
var text1 = "This is a sentence. It is a pencil."
text2 = modify(text1);
```

I want text2 to be "That was a sentence. I was a pencil."

So modify function replaces This->That  ,  is->was

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace all instances of the substring `is` with `was` you can use the [`replace`<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method:

```
text2 = text1.replace(/is/g, "was");
```

Note that because `is` is a part of the word `this`, it will actually return

> Thwas was a sentence

If you wanted to replace all instances of `This` to `That` and `is` to `was`, you could chain the calls to the `replace` method.

```
text2 = text1.replace(/This/g, "That").replace(/is/g, "was");
```

This will correctly do  your replacement from

> This is a sentence. It is a pencil.

to

> That was a sentence. It was a pencil.

You can [see this in action on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/N4BnY/)

---

**Note that find and replace actions like this can always have unintended consequences**. For example, this string

> Thistles and thorns are bad for missiles and corns.

will turn into this one after your replacement:

> Thatles and thorns are bad for mwassiles and corns.

This sort of thing is popularly known as [the Clbuttic mistake](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx).

Comment: What if there was more words to replace? If I want it to be "That was a sentence" ?  This->That  is->was

Comment: Is there a solution for that? I don't want to it to be "Thwas"

Comment: @Rckt It depends on what you're trying to do. In your case, only matching whole words might work well enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
text1 = text1.replace('is', 'was');
```

Btw, .replace accepts regular expressions as well

Comment: What if there was more words to replace? If I want it to be "That was a sentence" ?  This->That  is->was

Comment: Note that this will only replace the first instance of `is`.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the javascript replace method -

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Note:  To replace every occurrence of a string in JavaScript, you must provide the replace() method a regular expression with a global modifier as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript's [Replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function like this:

```
var text2 = text1.replace('is','was');
```